Rails autoloader is making private constants public
I'm trying to enforce a boundary in a Rails app: only code within the namespace Boundary should be able to access the class Boundary::Blackbox.
This works alright when it's defined outside of an autoloaded path:
# app/lib/boundary/blackbox.rb
module Boundary
  module Blackbox
    def self.foo
      "from foo"
    end
  end

  private_constant :Blackbox
end

# app/lib/boundary.rb
module Boundary
  def self.bridge
    "from bridge > " + Blackbox.foo
  end
end

# app/lib/outside.rb
module Outside
  def self.violation
    "from violation > " + Boundary::Blackbox.foo
  end
end

I expect the ruby code to make Boundary::Blackbox private, and indeed it is private except when Boundary::Blackbox is defined where the autoloader expects to find it.
Suppose I define it in example.rb instead:
load "example.rb"
Boundary.bridge # => "from bridge > from foo"
Outside.violation # => NameError uninitialized constant Boundary::Blackbox
Boundary::Blackbox.foo # => NameError uninitialized constant Boundary::Blackbox

Now let's test it using app/lib/boundary/blackbox.rb:
load "app/lib/boundary/blackbox.rb"
Boundary.bridge # => "from bridge > from foo"
Outside.violation # => "from violation > from foo"
Boundary::Blackbox.foo # => "from foo"

Now I get no NameError; Boundary::Blackbox is completely accessible.
How can I make my Boundary::Blackbox module private but also keep it in a location where the autoloader expects to find it?
(TMI: I do want it autoloaded so that Boundary.bridge can access it automatically, but I don't want to put it into app/lib/boundary.rb because that file would grow prohibitively unwieldy with the various modules/classes which need to go into the Boundary namespace. And I'm loath to put it into a file that falls outside the autoloader's pattern because I need to uphold conventions in a very large application.)

I can't reproduce.  What version of Rails are you on?  Are you using the zeitwerk autoloader?

@cschroed I'm using Rails 4.2. So we don't have zeitwerk yet. (Yes, it's deplorable to be on such an old version. But our org is making progress since last year at catching up to the rest of the world.)

@engineersmnky good point. Chalk that up to sloppy coping on my part. I've re-done my test and copy-pasted a correction for app/lib/outside.rb

I am unable to reproduce using basic autoload Example
